# How to cut DataTable's Columns by using a string array?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable, c#-3.0

I have a DataTable. How to cut out its columns, and return a new DataTable?

I'm trying to create a method with the following parameters:

- `DataTable dt`.
- A string Array containing some fields.

It should look something like this:

```
    public static DataTable cutDataTable(DataTable dt, List<string> fileds)
    {
        DataTable newDt = null;

          // processing code...

        return newDt
    }
```

No exceptions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to select only a few fields from a Datatable ?

Comment: yeah, And after that  return a new DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [DataView.ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.8) method for the purpose. For example,

```
var fields = new []{"Age","Id"}; //Fields to be selected.
var result = new DataView(table).ToTable(false, fields);
```

This would return a new DataTable from the source table with only the specified fields.

Comment: @GFLEE Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do something like this:

```
public static DataTable CutDataTable(DataTable dt, IList<string> columnsToRemove,
                                     bool keepData = true)
{
    DataTable newDt = (keepData ? dt.Copy() : dt.Clone());
    foreach (string colName in columnsToRemove)
    {
        if (!newDt.Columns.Contains(colName)) continue;
        newDt.Columns.Remove(colName);
    }

    return newDt;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
dt.Columns.Add("Column4");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4");

var newDt = CutDataTable(dt, new[] { "Column3", "Column4" });
Console.WriteLine("New column count = " + newDt.Columns.Count);
Console.WriteLine("First row data: " + string.Join(",", newDt.Rows[0].ItemArray));
```

**Output:**

```
New column count = 2
First row data: 1,2
```